# Homework task: Checking the equality of two arrays

Tags: c++

I am stuck on a homework question which requires me to create/modify a function which will set two arrays equal to each other. The question asks:

"Use the copy assignment (=) operator to set the two arrays equal to each other, this can be checked with the following:

```
y = x;
cout << "x equals y? " << (x == y) << endl; //Should return "True"
```

And is set within the following rules:

"Note that two Array objects should be considered equal only if they have the same length and the same element values."

This is the code I have, I have implemented two debugging sections which shows that they are indeed equal both in the assignment function and the main function, so my best guess is that the lengths don't match up. I am not allowed to modify any of the code which was provided (All the class and function stuff, or anything above the debugger in main), so I'm not sure how to set the lengths equal to each other in order to satisfy the condition (x==y)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// definition

#define MAX_LENGTH 100
#define INIT_VALUE 0

class Array {
public:
  Array(int length);
  Array& operator=(const Array& other);

  int length() const;
  int& operator[](int index);

  bool operator==(const Array& other) const;
  bool operator!=(const Array& other) const;

private:
  int length_;
  int elements_[MAX_LENGTH];
};

// implementation

Array::Array(int length) {
  length_ = length;
  if (length_ > MAX_LENGTH) length_ = MAX_LENGTH;
  for (int i = 0; i < length_; ++i) {
    elements_[i] = INIT_VALUE;
  }
}

Array& Array::operator=(const Array& other)
{
  /*DEBUG*/cout << endl << endl << "<<NOW IN ASSIGNMENT FUNCTION>>" << endl << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < other.length_; ++i)
  {
    elements_[i] = other.elements_[i];
    /*DEBUG*/cout << endl << "Elements: " << elements_[i] << " | Other Elements: " << other.elements_[i] << endl;
  }

  return *this;
}

int Array::length() const {
  return length_;
}

int& Array::operator[](int index) {
  // Q3 code goes here
  return elements_[index];
}

bool Array::operator==(const Array& other) const
{
  if (length_ != other.length_) return false;
  for (int i = 0; i < other.length_; ++i) {
    if (elements_[i] != other.elements_[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

bool Array::operator!=(const Array& other) const
{
  if (length_ != other.length_)
  {
      return true;
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < other.length_; ++j)
  {
    if (elements_[j] != other.elements_[j]) return true;
  }

  return false;
}

// testing

int main()
{
  Array x(10);
  x[3] = 42;
  cout << "x contains ";
  for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); ++i) {
    cout << x[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;

  Array y(5);
  cout << boolalpha;
  cout << "x equals y? " << (x == y) << endl;
  cout << "x notequals y? " << (x != y) << endl;
  y = x;

  //DEBUG SECTION
  cout << endl << endl << "<<NOW IN MAIN>>" << endl << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); ++i)
  {
    cout << endl << "Elements: " << x[i] << " | Other Elements: " << y[i] << endl;
  }
  //END OF DEBUG SECTION
  cout << "x equals y? " << (x == y) << endl;
}
```

So the question is, how can I get these arrays to have the same length without modifying them in 'main'? Can I do this through the assignment function?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You don't assign the `length_` variable in the assignment operator.

Comment: If two arrays are created with different lengths, how do you expect to be able to get them "to have the same length without modifying them in `main()`"?  Getting two different things to be the same (however you define "different" and "same") involves modifying at least one of them.

Comment: i don't know, that's why I asked. How can I get them to have the same lengths, in order to satisfy "Two Array objects should be considered equal only if they have the same length and the same element values."

Comment: Not related to your question, but... what if you instanciate an Array with size > MAX_LENGTH? (hint: => BOOM!) it's generally a BAD idea to use a statically sized array to store a conceptually dynamic array.

Comment: Suggestion: learn to leverage the C++ standard library and use std::vector instead.

Comment: @roalz It's quite clear from the question that "just use `std::vector`" is not an option for this task, just like "prove the Pythagorean theorem" should not be answered with "others have proven that it's true, Q.E.D.".

Comment: @MaxLanghof It's quite clear mine was a suggestion, aimed at learn to use C++ proficiently, and not an answer. If I wanted to give an answer I would have rather written an answer, instead of a comment.

Comment: @roalz The issue is that, despite your best intentions, your comment comes off as slightly patronizing. The imperative (directed at the asker) implies that the asker doesn't know how to leverage the standard library or how to use `std::vector`, which can't be concluded from the original question. Calling it a suggestion does not help much. A version like "For the record, one would usually work with `std::vector` instead of a custom-made dynamic array" would be preferred imo.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I'm not a native English speaker, my written English may be poor I know, and too synthetic. If the OP knows about std::vector she may just ignore my suggestion, in all other cases, IMHO it's still valid. For any other comment about my English and my suggestion, please feel free to contact me directly and not bother the SO community further. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You just forgot to assign the same length in the the `Array::operator=`.

This can be done by writing `this->length_ = other.length_;` in the

`Array& Array::operator=(const Array& other)` before overwriting the array.

Comment: Or just `length_ = other.length_`. Don't make `this->` a habit. +1.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, you did not asign the length correctly in the `= operator`.

Fix like this:

```
Array& Array::operator=(const Array& other)
{
   length_ = other.length_;
   for (int i = 0; i < length_; ++i)
   {
      elements_[i] = other.elements_[i];
   }
   return *this;
}
```

Also you can simplify your `!= operator` drastically

```
bool Array::operator!=(const Array& other) const
{
    return !(*this == other);
}
```

However, in my opinon even more important, you should also make use of the std-containers which allow dynamic sizes such as `std::vector`. This also would have avoided your bug.

In my opinion you should use these std-containers as soon as possible and get used to them. They are almost always the right choice when in doubt.

With `std::vector` your program could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// definition

#define INIT_VALUE 0

class Array {
public:
    Array(int length);
    Array& operator=(const Array& other);

    int length() const;
    int& operator[](int index);

    bool operator==(const Array& other) const;
    bool operator!=(const Array& other) const;

private:
    std::vector<int> elements_;
};

// implementation

Array::Array(int length)
:
elements_(length, INIT_VALUE)
{   
}

Array& Array::operator=(const Array& other)
{
    /*DEBUG*/cout << endl << endl << "<<NOW IN ASSIGNMENT FUNCTION>>" << endl << endl;
    elements_ = other.elements_;

    return *this;
}

int Array::length() const {
    return static_cast<int>(elements_.size());
}

int& Array::operator[](int index) {
    // Q3 code goes here
    return elements_[index];
}

bool Array::operator==(const Array& other) const
{
    return elements_ == other.elements_;
}

bool Array::operator!=(const Array& other) const
{
    return !(*this == other);
}

// testing

int main()
{
    Array x(10);
    x[3] = 42;
    cout << "x contains ";
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); ++i) {
        cout << x[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    Array y(5);
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << "x equals y? " << (x == y) << endl;
    cout << "x notequals y? " << (x != y) << endl;
    y = x;

    //DEBUG SECTION
    cout << endl << endl << "<<NOW IN MAIN>>" << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); ++i)
    {
        cout << endl << "Elements: " << x[i] << " | Other Elements: " << y[i] << endl;
    }
    //END OF DEBUG SECTION
    cout << "x equals y? " << (x == y) << endl;
}
```

Comment: With `std::vector<>` loop inside `operator==` is not necessary either, `std::vector::operator==` handles that

Comment: whoops! Did it too quickly. Thanks